# Заменить строку по классу

Tags: javascript, jquery

В прогресс баре динамично набирается процент (анимация).

Нужно перебить и в любом случае поставить там вместо процентов восклицательный знак (`!`).

Я пишу так:

```
function notznak() {
    var str = $( ".pie_progress__number" ).text();
    if (str != '!'){
        $( ".pie_progress__number" ).text( '!' );
    }
}
setTimeout(notznak, 1000);
```

Заменяет в процессе, но в конце все равно остается процент, вместо восклицательного знака.

Comment: Что даст `console.log(str)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$( ".pie_progress__number" ).after("<span>!</span>");
$( ".pie_progress__number" ).hide();
```